# onActivityResult(...) not called for a SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

I'm having problems with `onActivityResult(...)` not being called. I'm adapting working code from another app where it all works but I'm now using `Fragments`.

The main `Activity` is as follows...

```
public class RecordingsPagerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity 
    implements RecordingsListFragment.Callbacks {

    private final int SHOW_DETAIL_DIALOG = 1234;

    // RecordingsListFragment.Callbacks method
    @Override
    public void onRecordingsItemSelected(int oid) {
        showGuideDetailDialog(oid);
    }

    ...

    private void showGuideDetailDialog(int oid) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GuideDetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("oid", oid);
        startActivityForResult(i, SHOW_DETAIL_DIALOG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() entered - requestCode: " + requestCode + " - resultCode: " + resultCode);

        ...
    }
}
```

Basically when a list item in a `Fragment` is selected, the `Fragment` calls the `onRecordingsItemSelected(...)` callback method and `GuideDetailActivity` (which extends `Activity`) shows up fine. Depending on a button I select, the `onClick(...)` method in `GuideDetailActivity` sets a result and calls `finish()`.

The problem is, I never see the output of `Log.d(...)` in logcat. As I said, it works fine in an app created using just `Activities` (it's literally copied/pasted from my original source).

Is there something that would cause a `FragmentActivity` to  not receive the result meaning I need to do things differently?

Comment: Do you have any fragments that implement `onActivityResult()`?

Comment: No. Should I? Or do you mean they may be intercepting the result?

Comment: Fragments can also use `startActivityForResult()` and implement `onActivityResult()`. The framework is supposed to route the results to the right spot (based on the `requestCode` AFAIK). I was asking in case your fragment might be interfering with the main activity in this area. If you get stumped, and if you can create a sample project that reproduces your problem, post it somewhere, and I'll take a peek at it.

Comment: @CommonsWare : OK, thanks for the thoughts. I'm beginning to think I ought to use the `Fragment` methods for `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` anyway as there are subtle differences between the 4 fragments in the pager. I can then just use a callback from the `onActivityResult()` method in the fragments to the `FragmentActivity`. Thanks for your time.